# Zip a folder with specified path separator that will work in windows and Linux using dotnetzip library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dotnetzip

When i am zipping a folder with DotNetZip, it working properly, but when unzipping the zipped folder in Linux based server it is not working. The server team told me that While zipping the file use ‘/’ instead of ‘\’ as our system is Linux based.

How can i mention a path separator when zipping folder with DotNetZip?

Below is the code for zipping my folder.

```
ZipFile zp = new ZipFile();
            zipfileName = Server.MapPath("~/folder") + @"/" + folderName + @".zip";


            if (Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
            {
                zp.AddDirectory(directoryPath, folderName);
                zp.Save(zipfileName);
            }
```

Comment: Do you need to add a directory to the zip file at all?

Comment: i just want to zip a folder that am passing to save function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I changed my code as below, its working now.

```
Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zp = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile(); 
zp.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.Always;
zp.AlternateEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
zp.AddDirectory(directoryPath, folderName);
zp.Save(zipfileWithPathAndName);
```

Comment: You should never be doing `zipfileName = Server.MapPath("~/folder") + @"/" + folderName + @".zip";` and instead using `Path.Combine()`!